# Dualboot Antergos and Windows 10: No bootloader partition created by Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, antergos

I just installed Winodws 10. It was a clean install. Now I would like to install Antergos alongside Windows. After the installation of Windows 10, I have 3 partitions. A system reserved partition 500 MB (NTFS), C (NTFS) the primary partition and an empty partition 858 MB (entry for filesystem empty). According to [this](https://antergos.com/wiki/install/how-to-dual-boot-antergos-windows-uefi-expanded-by-linuxhat/) you need to create root, swap, home and windows should already have created a /boot/efi. But there is none. I only have those 3 aforementioned partitions. Am I supposed to create one myself or not? I would appreciate any help

Comment: The article you linked talks about UEFI Windows/Antergos dual booting. Either look for the one that talks about BIOS/legacy dual booting, or reinstall your Windows in UEFI boot mode (only if your machine has UEFI instead of BIOS).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a boot partition for your antergos to work.
Just create this partition (only /boot) and remember it's mount point e.g. `/Dev/sda8`

At some point the installer prompts you to select the mount point on which to install the boot files. Specify the boot mount point. When the installation is complete go to your windows system. From there add a boot entry using **easyBCD**. The type should be syslinux (not grub2) and the boot partition should be specified. Select the partition with the size matching the size of boot partition you created.